# i've created a interactive report in oracle apex and i want to connect different links to different rows of the same column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

this is my oracle apex report page i'm having a problem in. It has a interactive report which has 2 columns but both the rows of the same column refer to the same page in the application or for the matter to same url. i want to give different link to different rows of the same column.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) please read it first and edit question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create links manually for each row. For example (taken from one of my IRs):

```
SELECT   
  'f?p=&APP_ID.:' || case when r.id_obr = 6 then 217
                          when r.id_obr = 7 then 221
                     end ||
  ':&APP_SESSION.::NO::' || case when r.id_obr = 6 then 'P217_ID_OBR6'
                                 when r.id_obr = 7 then 'P221_ID_OBR7'
                            end ||
  ':' || r.id_obr67
  as link, ...
```

Created in such a way, it'll take you wherever you want, passing any values you want to any page you want.

Comment: Please don't use &APP_SESSION. inside SQL, use :SESSION instead
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/02/apex-variables-in-sql.html

Comment: Aha. Hard parse. Thank you, @Scott. Though, did you actually mean, `:app_session`? Based on what I read on your site, the *good query* example looks like `'f?p='||:app_id||':1:'||:app_session lnk` so - is it `:session`, or `:app_session`?

Comment: Tried it myself; it is `&SESSION.`, after all.

Comment: Hmm, I typed a reply, but I musn't have pressed 'Add'. Documentation mentions both https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/understanding-substitution-strings.html#GUID-E6B36FCC-3756-4F24-B6C0-A0798E605E9E but SESSION only exampled as v(). I know sometimes it is not recognised.

Comment: No problem, @Scott :)

Answer (score 0):

We dont know what version of apex you are on, but I will just give you the answer that works for me.

Create the links on each column and then create hidden page items on the page you are linking to, then using the links, have them set a value to those page items based on what was clicked.

Then you can just use those page items in your SQL query on the page you are linking to.
Or you could even use those items to create filters, but those a pain in the ass to set up, so I would suggest adding the items to your query for simplicity.